# Display JSON Result Upon Button Click ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have this code in my controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CalculateAndSaveToDB(BMICalculation CalculateModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            CalculateModel.Id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            CalculateModel.Date = System.DateTime.Now;
            CalculateModel.BMICalc = CalculateModel.CalculateMyBMI(CalculateModel.Weight, CalculateModel.Height);
            CalculateModel.BMIMeaning = CalculateModel.BMIInfo(CalculateModel.BMICalc);
            db.BMICalculations.Add(CalculateModel);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Json(new {CalculatedBMI = CalculateModel.BMICalc.ToString(), CalculatedBMIMeaning = CalculateModel.BMIMeaning.ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I would like to display CalculatedModel.BMICalc and CalculatedModel.BMIMeaning on the page using this JavaScript:

```
$('#good').click(function () {
    var request = new BMICalculation();
    $.ajax({
        url: "CalculateAndSaveToDB",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(request),
        success: function (response) {
            var div = $('#ajaxDiv');
            div.html("<br/> " + "<b>" + "Your BMI Calculations: " + "</b>");
            printBMI(div, response);
        },
    });
});

function printBMI(div, data) {
    div.append("<br/>" + "You are " + response.CalculatedBMI + ".");
    div.append("<br/>" + "You exact BMI is: " + response.CalculatedBMIMeaning + ".");
};
```

Nothing happens however when I do the button click. The correct data from form goes correctly into DB. My Chrome debugger says however that CalculateAndSaveToDB isn't found 404 error. Please help.

Comment: Maybe you are in a different controller. Try adding the controller name. not just the action in the ajax url. Example:  $.ajax({
        url: "MyController/CalculateAndSaveToDB", /*More parameters...*/ });

Comment: Tried that and not working still. I think it may be to do with my response not being passed correctly?

Comment: Set cache:false in the $.ajax request. Sometimes the browser caches the response

Comment: Also, make sure you are passing a variable called "CalculateModel" into your action

Answer (score 0):

Try to return false at the end of your click function.

```
$('#good').click(function () {
  //Your code      
  return false;    
});
```

Also I can see an error in your printBMI function. There is not reference to the variable "response". It should be "data"

```
function printBMI(div, data) {
  div.append("<br/>" + "You are " + data.CalculatedBMI + ".");
  div.append("<br/>" + "You exact BMI is: " + data.CalculatedBMIMeaning + ".");
};
```

Comment: How do I ensure my controller return is in fact putting my response in the data?

Comment: You can use fiddler to debug the response coming from the server. http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 0):

There might be several problems:

1. Your routing is not correct and the post-action cannot be invoked. I dont see any information about routing, so this might be a problem.
2. You do not return false, as suggested by PraveeReddy. If you dont do so, the browser follows the link of your button.

Just a hint: In such simple scenarios it can be easier to use $.load: http://api.jquery.com/load/